# While I make the source of Android 6.0, it failed

Tags: android, curl

When I execute the "make" command of source of Android 6.0, it failed. Here is the error message, I can't see and don't find any resolve method.

Please help me.

> [ 31% 8837/27694] Build:
>   out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/jack_intermediates/jack FAILED:
>   /bin/bash -c "(true) && (out/host/darwin-x86/bin/jack-admin
>   install-server out/host/darwin-x86/framework/jack-launcher.jar
>   out/host/darwin-x86/framework/jack-server.jar  2>&1 || (exit 0)) &&
>   (JACK_SERVER_VM_ARGUMENTS=\"-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
>   -XX:+TieredCompilation\" out/host/darwin-x86/bin/jack-admin start-server 2>&1 || exit 0) && (out/host/darwin-x86/bin/jack-admin
>   update server out/host/darwin-x86/framework/jack-server.jar 4.1.ALPHA
>   2>&1 || exit 0) && (out/host/darwin-x86/bin/jack-admin update jack
>   prebuilts/sdk/tools/jacks/jack-2.23.RELEASE.jar 2.23.RELEASE || exit
>   47; out/host/darwin-x86/bin/jack-admin update jack
>   prebuilts/sdk/tools/jacks/jack-3.2.ALPHA.jar 3.2.ALPHA || exit 47) &&
>   (mkdir -p out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/jack_intermediates/) &&
>   (out/host/darwin-x86/bin/acp -fp prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack
>   out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/jack_intermediates/jack)" Writing
>   client settings in /Users/jon/.jack-settings Unsupported curl, please
>   use a curl not based on SecureTransport Launching Jack server java
>   -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/folders/ym/_dhlr3xd0gz372gphbc0b37r0000gn/T/ -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:+TieredCompilation -cp /Users/jon/.jack-server/launcher.jar
>   com.android.jack.launcher.ServerLauncher
>   out/host/darwin-x86/bin/jack-admin: line 259:
>   /Users/jon/.jack-server/logs/outputs.txt: No such file or directory
>   Jack server failed to (re)start, see Jack server log Unsupported curl,
>   please use a curl not based on SecureTransport Unsupported curl,
>   please use a curl not based on SecureTransport ninja: build stopped:
>   subcommand failed. make: *** [ninja.intermediate] Error 1
>
> make failed to build some targets (02:41:43 (hh:mm:ss))

Comment: Same problem, I'm using Mac OS X el capitan, any suggestions?

Comment: Could you add the results of "curl --version" to the question?

Comment: How did you access the `jack-admin` command?

Answer (score 16):

Easy alternative when using Homebrew:

```
brew install curl --with-openssl
export PATH=$(brew --prefix curl)/bin:$PATH
caffeinate make -j4
```

Note: `caffeinate` is just to prevent OS X from sleeping

Comment: Where is `-j4` located?

Comment: This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Check your current curl version as following:

```
$ /usr/bin/curl --version
curl 7.43.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.0) libcurl/7.43.0 SecureTransport zlib/1.2.5
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz UnixSockets
```

If the output include **SecureTransport**, You need install a curl compiled with openssl.

Download CURL source code from http://curl.haxx.se/download.html, then compile it like:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/curl --with-ssl=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2d_1
make && make install
```

Then add following line to your .bashrc

```
export PATH="/usr/local/curl/bin:$PATH"
```

open a a new terminal, check curl version, it should be something as following:

```
$ curl --version
curl 7.46.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.2.0) libcurl/7.46.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2d zlib/1.2.5
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

Comment: After `configure`, you need do `make` and `make install`, thanks. It help me.

Answer (score 0):

The error appears to be “Unsupported curl, please use a curl not based on SecureTransport”. It looks like you're running on a Mac from the error message's file URIs.

I think you may have missed (or a Mac update replaced) one of the packages that are required to be installed to build Android from source. Could you [check the page](https://source.android.com/source/initializing.html#installing-required-packages) and re-run the installation of the packages from the "macports" area?

Before updating the packages using macports please run this command in the terminal and add the resulting output as an update to your question. `curl --version`