# Build android source faile

Tags: android, build, makefile

```
FAILED: /bin/bash -c "(true) && (out/host/darwin-x86/bin/jack-admin install-server out/host/darwin-x86/framework/jack-launcher.jar out/host/darwin-x86/framework/jack-server.jar  2>&1 || (exit 0)) && (JACK_SERVER_VM_ARGUMENTS=\"-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-XX:+TieredCompilation\" out/host/darwin-x86/bin/jack-admin start-server 2>&1 || exit 0) && (out/host/darwin-x86/bin/jack-admin update server out/host/darwin-x86/framework/jack-server.jar 4.1.ALPHA 2>&1 || exit 0) && (out/host/darwin-x86/bin/jack-admin update jack prebuilts/sdk/tools/jacks/jack--1.1.PRE_ALPHA.jar -1.1.PRE_ALPHA || exit 47; out/host/darwin-x86/bin/jack-admin update jack prebuilts/sdk/tools/jacks/jack-2.24.RELEASE.jar 2.24.RELEASE || exit 47; out/host/darwin-x86/bin/jack-admin update jack prebuilts/sdk/tools/jacks/jack-3.2.ALPHA.jar 3.2.ALPHA || exit 47) && (mkdir -p out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/jack_intermediates/) && (out/host/darwin-x86/bin/acp -fp prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/jack_intermediates/jack)"

Unsupported curl, please use a curl not based on SecureTransport
Launching Jack server java -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/folders/z9/xxg7q0l94nv7vn412lc6scjm0000gn/T/ -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:+TieredCompilation -cp /Users/Crush/.jack-server/launcher.jar com.android.jack.launcher.ServerLauncher
out/host/darwin-x86/bin/jack-admin: line 248: /Users/Crush/.jack-server/logs/outputs.txt: No such file or directory
Jack server failed to (re)start, see Jack server log

Unsupported curl, please use a curl not based on SecureTransport
Unsupported curl, please use a curl not based on SecureTransport
```

Comment: What is your question? What is the content of your message? COuld you format it better?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33318756/while-i-make-the-source-of-android-6-0-it-failed Someone with enough reputation points please mark it as such.

Comment: Duplicated with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33318756/while-i-make-the-source-of-android-6-0-it-failed Please see answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33318756/while-i-make-the-source-of-android-6-0-it-failed/34552218#34552218

Comment: Possible duplicate of [While I make the source of Android 6.0, it failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33318756/while-i-make-the-source-of-android-6-0-it-failed)